# PostgreSQL11 space reuse under high delete/update rate

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

We are evaluating PostgreSQL 11.1 for our production. 
Having a system with 4251 updates per second, ~1000 deletes per second and   ~3221 inserts per second and 1 billion transactions per day, we face a challenge where PostgreSQL does not reuse its (delete/update) space, and tables constantly increase in size.

We configured aggressive Autovacuum settings to avoid the wraparound situation. also tried adding periodic execution of `vacuum analyze` and `vacuum` – 
and still there is no space reuse. (Only `vacuum full` or `pg_repack` release space to operating system – but this is not a reuse.)

Following are our vacuum settings:

```
autovacuum                          | on
vacuum_cost_limit                   | 6000
autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 5
autovacuum_max_workers              | 32
autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 2000000
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 2000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age             | 20000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age   | 20000
vacuum_cost_page_dirty              | 20
vacuum_freeze_min_age               | 10000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age     | 10000
log_autovacuum_min_duration         | 1000
autovacuum_naptime                  | 10
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0
vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor   | 0
vacuum_cost_delay                   | 0
vacuum_defer_cleanup_age            | 0
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1
autovacuum_work_mem                 | -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are particularly hard for PostgreSQL.

- You should set `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` to 0 for that table.
- Reset `autovacuum_max_workers` and `autovacuum_naptime` back to their default values.
- Reset `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` and `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` to their default values or slightly lower values.

Your problem is *not* that autovacuum does not run often enough, the problem is rather that it is too slow to keep up.

Even with that you might only be able to handle this workload with HOT updates:

- Make sure that the attributes that are updated a lot are *not* part of any index.
- Create the table with a `fillfactor` below 100, say 70.

HOT update often avoids the need for `VACUUM` and the need to update indexes.

Check the `n_tup_hot_upd` column of `pg_stat_us-er_tables` to see if it works.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thanks much for the answer. does it make sense to cancel the "scale_factors" and use "threshold" instead when table rows grow fast and scale are percentage of total rows  and "threshold" is fixed number?  thanks Aliza.

Comment: That is indeed a useful option.